# Reuse a calculated measure that uses sum

Tags: ssas, mdx

I know some basic MDX but cannot seem to create a calculated measure that uses a sum over a date set of another calculated measure that also sums another measure over the same date set.

The background is that I am trying to calculate the least squares estimate of the coefficient of a simple linear regression with the intercept set to zero. I use this formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Linear_regression_without_the_intercept_term) to do it and this works fine. However I now want to calculate the standard error of that coefficient which involves estimating the sum of the squared residuals as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption).

Please see the code I have written so far below. Is this even possible with MDX?

```
With 

Member [Measures].[Renewed] As
    Sum([Customer Product Status].[Customer Product Status Rollup].&[Renewed], [Measures].[Product Count])

Member [Measures].[Renewed * Product Count] As
    [Measures].[Renewed] * [Measures].[Product Count]

Member [Measures].[Product Count * Product Count] As
    [Measures].[Product Count] * [Measures].[Product Count]

Member [Measures].[Product Count n] As
    Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, 1.0)

Member [Measures].[Product Count Mean] As
    Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Product Count]) / [Measures].[Product Count n]

Member [Measures].[Renewal Rate] As
    (Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Renewed * Product Count]))/
    (Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Product Count * Product Count]))

Member [Measures].[Sum of Squared Residuals] As
    Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, ([Measures].[Renewed] - [Measures].[Renewal Rate] * [Measures].[Product Count]) ^ 2.0)

Member [Measures].[Mean of Squared Residuals] As
    [Measures].[Sum of Squared Residuals] / ([Measures].[Product Count n] - 1)

Member [Measures].[Renewal Rate Standard Error] As
    ([Measures].[Mean of Squared Residuals]/Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Product Count * Product Count])) ^ 0.5

Member [Measures].[Renewal Rate Upper CI] As
    [Measures].[Renewal Rate] + 2.0 * [Measures].[Renewal Rate Standard Error]

Member [Measures].[Renewal Rate Lower CI] As
    [Measures].[Renewal Rate] - 2.0 * [Measures].[Renewal Rate Standard Error]

Set [Month Name] As 
    Filter(
        [Expiry Date].[Month Name].Children, 
        StrToMember("[Expiry Date].[Month Of Year Name].&[May]", CONSTRAINED) * StrToMember("[Expiry Date].[Year Name].&[2015]", CONSTRAINED)
    )

Set [Historical Months] As
    {[Month Name].Item(0).Lag(25) : [Month Name].Item(0).Lag(1)} * 
    [Expiry Date].[Month Date].Children *
    [Expiry Date].[Month of Year Name].Children *
    [Expiry Date].[Year Name].Children

Select Non Empty {[Measures].[Renewal Rate], 
    [Measures].[Renewal Rate Lower CI],
    [Measures].[Renewal Rate Upper CI]} On 0,
    Non Empty [Historical Months] On 1
From [Product Renewals]
```

Comment: `cannot seem to create a calculated measure that uses a sum over a date set of another calculated measure that also sums another measure over the same date set.`  - Where exactly are you having the issue? The only "date" set I see is `[Month Name]`. (Pls pardon my ignorance of statistical terms)

Comment: The primary issue is in the [Measures].[Sum of Squared Residuals] calculated member. The expression [Measures].[Renewal Rate] * [Measures].[Product Count] incorrectly results in 0.

Comment: I have a feeling summing [Measures].[Renewal Rate] * [Measures].[Product Count] over [Expiry Date].[Date].Children will not work as [Measures].[Renewal Rate] itself is a result of summing a measure over [Expiry Date].[Date].Children

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by rewriting the [Measures].[Sum of Squared Residuals] measure. If you expand the equation and take the [Measures].[Renewal Rate] out of the sum function then everything works. The expanded [Measures].[Sum of Squared Residuals] measure now looks like this:

```
Member [Measures].[Sum of Squared Residuals] As
    Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Renewed] * [Measures].[Renewed]) + 
    [Measures].[Renewal Rate] ^ 2.0 * Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Product Count * Product Count]) -
    2.0 * [Measures].[Renewal Rate] * Sum([Expiry Date].[Date].Children, [Measures].[Renewed * Product Count])
```

Excel Regression Results for April:
[image]

MDX Regression Results:
[image]

Comment: Great that you were able to get around it and thanks for sharing the tip!